# How to access Perfmon info?

Tags: c#, count, perfmon

I would like to get some NCache info as Perfmon sees in (eg: Count) but directly using C#.  Does anyone have any code for this, please?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the docs for [`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx)? I would expect them to give you a reasonable starting point.